# How would you pass the user's username and password for SSH in a Web Application (asp.net)

Tags: asp.net, ssh

I understand that this isn't necessarily the best style question for stackoverflow but with that said I have made a lot of questions regarding this question, but I want to know how you would handle it.

I am creating a web application in asp.net and I need to connect to a UNIX server to run remote perl scripts. I am currently doing this

```
Removed code for personal reasons
```

If I hardcode my username and password this works fine, but I am trying to create a modal window to pass the values through which may not be the most secure.

So, how would you accomplish this - this is subjective and I can close this question if need be...

EDIT:
I forgot to say, I will be connecting to many different servers, so a public/private key isn't the best option. Suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just run your site on https i.e install SSL certificate . this will encrypt the transmitted data. nothing will be transmitted as plain text.